# Django Heroku App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: django, python-2.7, heroku

I'm trying to push my existing Django project to Heroku using [heroku-django-template](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template) as a reference to modify my django project.

My interpreter is Python 2.7.14 and I didn't use virtual env.

But after a whole day of trying, I only got this error repeatedly:

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to py-mosaic-image.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/py-mosaic-image.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

here's my dictionary:

```
-- .git/
-- my-project/
---- some-app-dir/
---- some-app-dir/
---- my-project/
---- __init__.py
---- .env
---- db.sqlite3
---- manage.py
---- Pipfile
---- Pipfile.lock
---- Procfile
---- requirements.txt
---- runtime.txt
```

and here's some code (many are generated by heroku-django-template)

.env

```
WEB_CONCURRENCY=2
```

Pipfile (ignore some \r)

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[requires]
python_version = "2.7"

[packages]
dj-database-url = "==0.4.2"
django = "==2.0"
gunicorn = "==19.7.1"
"psycopg2" = "==2.7.3.2"
whitenoise = "==3.3.1"

[dev-packages]
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn py-mosaic-image.wsgi --log-file -
```

requirements.txt

```
attrs==17.4.0
autobahn==17.10.1
Automat==0.6.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.4
constantly==15.1.0
cycler==0.10.0
Django==1.8.18
django-socket-server==0.0.4
django-socketio==0.3.9
gevent==1.2.2
gevent-socketio==0.2.1
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==0.4.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
hyperlink==17.3.1
incremental==17.5.0
matplotlib==2.1.0
numpy==1.13.3
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.3.0
PyAudio==0.2.11
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.3
scipy==1.0.0
six==1.11.0
sphinx-me==0.3
Twisted==17.9.0
txaio==2.8.2
websocket==0.2.1
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

runtime.txt

```
python-2.7.14
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this? I searched and tried but all failed :(

Comment: You have `django = "==2.0"` in your `[packages]`, but Django 2.0 only supports Python 3.

Comment: I modified it to `django = "==1.8.18"` but the error remained

Comment: OK I solved it myself. This is ridiculous but the local branch I pushed isn't `master`. When I pushed from master, all is well. Pipfile is not needed too.